# Assigning variable to column with same name as another in a different table from JOIN

Tags: java, sql

I am doing a join to retrieve data from a database and am assigning it to variables

```
rs = select.executeQuery("SELECT PK_Task, PointPerson, Task.ScrumId, Story.ScrumId, Product.ScrumId FROM [Task] " +
    "INNER JOIN [Story] ON StoryId=PK_Story INNER JOIN [Product] ON ProductId=PK_Product WHERE Product.Deleted!=1");
```

To retrieve this data:

```
while(rs.next()) {
    String taskId = rs.getString("PK_Task");
}
```

But how to I get data from the columns that have the same name on different tables:

```
while(rs.next()) {
    Long taskScrumId = rs.getLong("Task.ScrumId");
}
```

Results in:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name Task.ScrumId is not valid.
```

Comment: Better way is to alias your columns if they have the same name...`SELECT PK_TASK, PointPerson, Task.ScrumID AS TheScrum...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use `getString(int)` or use `Task.ScrumID as task_scrum_id` and getString("task_scrum_id"). I personally prefer the latter approach.

So, in this case, the task would be

```
String taskId = rs.getString(3)
```

or your query would be

```
select.executeQuery("SELECT PK_Task, PointPerson, Task.ScrumId as task_scrum_id, ...

String taskId = rs.getString("task_scrum_id")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give the columns aliases.
Please take a look at the below example.

```
SELECT 
    TeacherName = T.Name
,   StudentName = S.Name
FROM Teachers T
JOIN Students S ON T.SomeValue = S.SomeValues
```